# Spring Boot Localhost https issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat

I wanted to make my localhost from hypertext transfer protocol to the secured socket layer hypertext transfer protocol. So I have added a key store to my spring boot project, and configured my application.properties like this:

**INFORMATION**

[image]

But I get an error in chrome that:

```
localhost uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR__VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

Note: I have done no changes to any of the java files.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this issue I solved it by a `bean` like below. hope this helps you

```
@Configuration
class CustomConfiguration {

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
final int port = 8443;
final String keystoreFile = "/path/to/keystore"
final String keystorePass = "keystore-password"
final String keystoreType = "pkcs12"
final String keystoreProvider = "SunJSSE"
final String keystoreAlias = "tomcat"

TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = 
        new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(this.port);
factory.addConnectorCustomizers( new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
    void    customize(Connector con) {
        Http11NioProtocol proto = (Http11NioProtocol) con.getProtocolHandler();
            proto.setSSLEnabled(true);
        con.setScheme("https");
        con.setSecure(true);
        proto.setKeystoreFile(keystoreFile);
        proto.setKeystorePass(keystorePass);
        proto.setKeystoreType(keystoreType);
        proto.setProperty("keystoreProvider", keystoreProvider);
        proto.setKeyAlias(keystoreAlias);
    }
});
return factory;
}
}
```

Also make sure you call keytool with `-storetype pkcs12`, not `-storepass pkcs12`